# Method of Calculating Efficient Points and Corresponding Weight Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I was doing exercises from Joel Franklin's Methods of Mathematical Economics out of personal interest and found myself a bit conflicted as to how I approached problem 8 in the Multiobjective Linear Programming Section. The question is find all efficient points $x$ and all their weight vectors $w$ for the following optimization problem,
$$
\min \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}x
$$
subject to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
4 \\
6
\end{bmatrix} \\
x \geq 0
$$
I approached this problem by simply calculating the basic solutions for every choice of $3$ columns in the constraint matrix, eliminating those which have negative components (and are therefore unfeasible), plotting the image of the feasible basic solutions under the cost matrix, and from the plot it becomes obvious the line segment adjoining solutions $ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T $ and $ \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 & 12 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T $ correspond to efficient solutions. Then again by looking at the plot I determined weight vectors by realizing that $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ has level set corresponding to the costs on the aforementioned efficient line segment. Any weight vector with larger second component would pick out $ \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 & 12 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T $, while larger first component would pick out $ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T $.

I have also sanity checked my solutions by using an online solver with the weight vectors I identified and do indeed get the expected efficient points as solutions.

With all that being said I am unsure if this is the "right" approach. Other problems or examples in the text are given this efficient solution / weight vector find the corresponding weight vector / efficient solution so there was not much reference to lean on. This problem asks for both efficient solutions and corresponding weight vectors and led me to realize I am actually unsure of a good method of even finding efficient solutions aside from just picking a random weight vector and solving. My current approach is basically brute force in checking all possible basic solutions, comparing all of them to determine which ones end up being efficient, and determining weights by inspection which seems inefficient and unsatisfying. The only other method I could think of was picking weight vectors at random and then calculating efficient solutions, but this again seems to be brute force in just looking randomly for basic efficient solutions until no more can exist. So more succinctly,

1. Is there a more efficient or even just another way to approach this problem than the "brute force" approach I ended up using?
2. Generally when given a multiobjective linear program and asked to compute efficient solutions what do people do? How could one neatly calculate all the efficient solutions (which I believe is also called the Pareto frontier)?
3. Is there anything wrong with my approach? Did I miss any efficient solutions or something like that? I don't think this is the case, but if I've made any glaring error correction would much be appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is OK, but there're more structured methods. You can use weighted sum approach or ε-constraint method. Some multiobjective problems have non-convex boundaries in the objective space. It might be necessary to consider non-basic solutions in those cases if there're larger number of objectives.